# inequality between matrix norms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A is a $n\times k $ matrix.

I have to show that $\|A\|_2\leq \sqrt{\|A\|_1\cdot \|A\|_\infty}$.

I know that $\|A\|_2^2 = \rho(A^H\cdot A)\leq \|A^H \cdot A\| $ for every $\| \cdot  \|$ submultiplicative matrix norm, but I don't know how to conclude.

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by $\rho(.)$?

Comment: tha maximum of the eigenvalues

Comment: I think $\lambda(.)$ would be a better notation in that case.

Comment: Usually we use $\rho(A)$ to denote the maximum of the eigenvalues (taking moduli) of $A$, and we call it the spectral radius of $A$, so I think this is the case. That is to say, let $\lambda _i$ be the eigenvalues of $A$, then $\rho (A) = \max \left\{ \left| \lambda _i \right| \right\} $.

Comment: here $\rho$ and $\lambda_\max$ agree as $A^H A$ is positive semidefinite...

Answer (score 3):

As you noted that you now the inequality $\|A\|_2^2=\rho(A^HA)$ then it is assumed that you work with the standard induced matrix norms.

The **definition** is as follows:

Let $B\in \mathbb R^{n\times k}$ and let $\|.\|$ is some vector norm in $\mathbb R^k$. Then the induced matrix norm, denoted again with $\|.\|$ is:
$$\|B\|=\sup\limits_{\vec x\in \mathbb R^k}{\frac{\|B\vec x\|}{\|\vec x\|}}$$
So we have:
$$\|A\|_2^2=\rho(A^HA)\leq \|A^HA\|_\infty\leq \|A^H\|_\infty\cdot \|A\|_\infty =\|A\|_1\cdot \|A\|_\infty$$.

The **first inequality** is known for you, as you said, and it is shown like this:

Let $\vec x$ be an eigenvector of $B$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$, where $\max\limits_{i}|\lambda_i|=|\lambda|$. Then for arbitrary matrix norm $\|.\|$, subordinate to the vector norm $\|.\|$, we have $\|B\|=\max\limits_{\vec y\neq \vec 0} \frac{\|B\vec y\|}{\|\vec y\|}\ge \frac{\|B\vec x\|}{\|\vec x\|}=\frac{\|\lambda \vec x\|}{\|\vec x\|}=|\lambda|$

The **second inequality** is because the $\|.\|_\infty$ is induced norm from the vector $\infty$ - norm, so it is sub-multiplicative.

The **last equality** is because $\|A^H\|_\infty$ is the maximum absolute row sum of the matrix $A^H$, which is equal to the maximum absolute column sum of $A$ which is equal to the $\|A\|_1$ .

Answer (score 2):

or use  $\|A\|_2^2 = \rho(A^H\cdot A)\leq \|A^H \cdot A\| _\infty\leq\|A^H\|_\infty \cdot \|A\|_\infty \leq \|A\|_1.\|A\|_\infty$

Because $\|A^H\|_\infty=\|A\|_1 $

Comment: he has mentioned it in the question that he know it.

Comment: oh sorry. I missed that

Comment: @Razieh Noori Isn't it $\|A^H\|_\infty=\|A\|_1$ ?

Comment: @Svetoslav No, dear. $\|A\|_\infty $ is operator norm, which is equal to biggest singular value, but $\|A\|_1$ is sum of singular values. see the reference i have said in first answer. those are interesting norms on matrices (called schatten p-norm)

Comment: @Razieh Noori , see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm

Comment: @Razieh Noori , you are using Schatten norms, which are different from the induced matrix norms, but are denoted the same way. Probably you missunderstood something from the book you cited. In the question it is most likely assumed the induced matrix norms !

Comment: thanks, you are right, since when i concentrate now. for schatten 2-norm, we dont have $\|A\|_2^2 = \rho(A^H\cdot A)$

Answer (score 0):

$\|A\|_{2}^2\leq trac(A^H\cdot A)\leq{\Vert A^H\cdot A\Vert_1\leq  \| A\|_1\|A\| _\infty}$.

for more information see $D.46$ and $D.52$ of abstract harmonic analysis hewitt&ross pages 706 and 709

Comment: here $\|\cdot\|_2$ looks like the operator norm than the Frobenius norm. So it should be $\le trace(A^H A)$.

Comment: then what is $\|A\|_\infty$ ?

Comment: the operator norm to the vector norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$

Comment: thus i think my below answer is better than this one

Comment: probably ${}{}{}$